# Focus + Context + Update data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I reproduced [THIS example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) with a line chart to achieve the brushing feature via focus and context. Now I want to insert periodically new data to my line chart. I do this with:

```
     // Push new value in dataset
    values.push(newdataObject);

    // Write new datapoints in graph
    x.domain(d3.extent(values, function(d) { return parseDate(d.timestamp); }));

    // Make transition
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750);      
    t.select(".line").attr("d", main_line(values));
    t.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
```

This works when I see the whole graph without brushing anything.

Problem: When I brush a part of the bottom graph and get an update, the upper focused graph fills up again with all data while the bottom graph still keeps brushed. How to keep the focus of the main graph?

Edit:

My brushing function:

```
    function brushed() {
      x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
      focus.select(".line").attr("d", main_line);
      focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }
```

Comment: Don't set `x.domain()` in your update function.

Comment: Ok true. But I want to rescale the main graph, when there is no brush.

Comment: You can check if the brush is empty with `brush.empty()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick responses!